# css:- changing { height: fixed } to {height : fit to content}

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div> line 1 <br>
  line 2  <br>
  line 3  <br>
  line 4  <br>
  ...     ...
</div
```

css:-

```
div {
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').css('height', xxx)
```

can i use the above jQuery code or any other, to make `height` of div flexible again, ie, to fit the content rather than be predetermined manually?

Comment: Why not use only `css` with `height:auto` ?

Comment: [css only](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bVMNZ/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `auto`, the default value for `height`, to achieve that:

```
$('div').css('height', 'auto')
```

Comment: the other answer of setting height to "" would also work to allow the height to default to a property higher up in the hierarchy. For example, if `body { height:100%; }` was set, setting `.css('height','')` would allow it to pick up the `100%`.

Comment: True, but the OP specified the element's height should be resized to fit its content, not to have any other property values in its hierarchy applied.

Answer (score 2):

Create a second class declaration in your CSS file called "flexible"

```
.flexible{
  height: auto !important;
}
```

and then use jQuery to add the class

```
$('div').addClass('flexible');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WQcHs/